# How to convert an array into an array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, arrayobject

My scenario is where i will upload a text file contain data like this

```
a1,b1,,c1,d1,
a2,b2,,c2,d2,
```

From the data, i able read and split it with ("\n") and result is

```
array=[array[0]:[a1,b1,,c1,d1]
       array[1]:[a2,b2,,c2,d2]]
```

How can i populate the array above into my array object?

sample output:

```
newarray=[[name="a1",age:"b2",address="",contact="c1",gender="d1"],
           [name="a2",age:"b2",address="",contact="c2",gender="d2"]]
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Creating a array using a string which contains the key and the value of the properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40507402/4543207)

Comment: @Redu It similar to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489345/transform-all-array-keys-with-values-from-another-array) but from the link the solution is to provide the key, what if just only stated the data without the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the position of each attribute in the array seems to be fixed, i would just create a function with a fixed assignment. Like this:

```js
var str = "a1,b1,,c1,d1,\na2,b2,,c2,d2,";
var objects = parseString(str);
console.log(objects);

function parseString(strIn){
  var objectList = [];
  var splitResult = strIn.split("\n");
  for(var i=0;i<splitResult.length;i++){
    var valueArray = splitResult[0].split(",");
    objectList.push(mapToObject(valueArray));
  }
  return objectList;
}

function mapToObject(array){
  return {
    name: array[0],
    age:array[1],
    address: array[2],
    contact: array[3],
    gender:array[4]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function arrToObj(arr){
 var newArr = [];
 arr.forEach(function(value,index){
     obj = {};
     obj.name = value[0];
     obj.age = value[1];
     obj.contact = value[2];
     newArr.push(obj);

});
return newArr;
}
```